# Animation with scale and translate - scrollTo position after click anchor link

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll, anchor-scroll

I built a menu with anchor links to sections.

For each section, I have animation to appear on scroll (opacity, translate, scale change).
I use the AOS animation library (https://github.com/michalsnik/aos).

My target is to scroll to the correct position of the clicked link (anchor).

My code example:
https://codepen.io/matteokrr/pen/VwqKxbL

JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this.hash);

  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 2000, 'swing');
  }
});
```

CSS animation:

```
[data-aos='zoom-in-down'] {
  transform: translate3d(0, -200px, 0) scale(.6);
}
```

**The problem:**

When the targeted section is not visible yet, then the offset top position of the section is wrong.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the animation process in jquery (https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options).

Try this out:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, {
  duration: 2000,
  easing: 'swing',
  step: function (now, tween) {
    if (tween.end !== target.offset().top) {
      tween.end = target.offset().top
    }
  }
});
```